# Why is my class not being applied to my navbar link?

Tags: html, css, class, navbar

I'm trying to style the Contact link in the navbar with the active class but it isn't working. The navbutton class is being applied to the other similar links though. I'm sure it's a simple fix but I'm new to this and just learning through Youtube.

```js
function initMap() {
  var location = {
    lat: X,
    lng: X
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: location
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

 :root {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 1440px;
}

html {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: dolce, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  color: rgba(218, 219, 162, 1);
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(254, 176, 42, 1);
  position: relative;
}

header {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-top: 46px;
}

nav {
  background-color: rgba(254, 176, 42, 1);
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
}

a:hover {
  color: rgba(91, 121, 168, 1);
}

a.navbutton {
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 13px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
}

a.active {
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgba(91, 121, 168, 1);
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 13px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
}

div.parallax1 {
  background-image: url(Images/YellowtoBlue.jpeg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 33vh;
}

h1 {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(254, 176, 42, 1);
  font-size: 47px;
  font-family: storefront-pro, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 13px;
}

main {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}

#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: visible;
}

form h2 {
  color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding: 23px 13px;
}

form {
  text-align: center;
}

fieldset {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(37, 37, 37, 1);
  border-color: rgba(190, 111, 159, 1);
}

legend {
  font-size: 23px;
  color: rgba(79, 204, 170, 1);
  text-align: center;
}

label {
  font-size: 18px;
}

input {
  background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
}

button {
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  background-color: rgba(80, 154, 217, 1);
}

button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(190, 111, 159, 1);
}

div.parallax2 {
  background-image: url(Images/YellowtoBlue.jpeg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 13vh;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="Test.html" class="navbutton">Home</a>
    <a href="Test-About.html" class="navbutton">About</a>
    <a href="Test-Contact.html" class="active">Contact</a>
    <a href="Test-Stock.html" class="navbutton">Stock</a>
  </nav>

  <div class="parallax1">
    <h1>Stangler Electronics</h1>
  </div>

</header>

<main>

  <div id="map" style="position: fixed; overflow: visible;"></div>

  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=;)&callback=initMap">
  </script>

  <form formaction="https://httpbin.org/post" formmethod="post">

    <h2>Get Ahold of us</h2>

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Your Message</legend>

      <label for="message"></label>
      <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="40" rows="10" style="background-color: rgba(51,51,51,1); color: rgba(79,204,170,1); font-size: 13px; padding: 10px 10px;" placeholder="Type Message Here.."></textarea><br>

    </fieldset><br>
    <div class="parallax2"></div>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Personal Information</legend>

      <label for="FirstName">*First Name&gt;</label>
      <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" placeholder="Jane" autocomplete="on" required autofocus><br><br>

      <label for="LastName">*Last Name&gt;</label>
      <input type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName" placeholder="Doe" autocomplete="on" required><br><br>

      <label for="Phone">*Phone&gt;</label>
      <input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]{3}[0-9]{3}[0-9]{4}" name="Phone" id="Phonee" placeholder="123-456-7890" autocomplete="on" required><br><br>

      <label for="EMail">E-Mail&gt;</label>
      <input type="email" name="EMail" id="EMail" placeholder="Example@gmail.com" autocomplete="on"><br><br>

      <button type="submit" formaction="https://httpbin.org/post" formmethod="post">Submit</button><br><br>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</main>
```

Also I know there is a map in there that's broken, but that's a whole other question lol

Comment: I see that it shows it as working in the snippet? My code is the same on Visual Studio but I get different results. The "Contact" is not styled at all, it is small different font and underlined.

Comment: did you already cleared your cache?

Comment: I have since reading your comment and still nothing has changed on my end.

Comment: Update: I applied the style directly to the "Contact" link in my HTML file and that worked just fine.

Comment: Update: I went back to my original code and then added nav before the a.active in my CSS and it worked.. so now it looks like "nav a.active {.. }"